# Confusing result with if / else statement

Tags: php, if-statement

this is some of my script so far:

```
$check = ("SELECT username FROM users WHERE username = '$us3r'");
$check2 = ("SELECT password FROM users WHERE username = '$us3r'");
$check3 = ("SELECT userID FROM users WHERE username = '$us3r'");
$check4 = ("SELECT userrole FROM users WHERE username = '$us3r'");

//Role

$role = mysql_query($check4);
$arr5 = mysql_fetch_row($role);
$roles = ($arr5[0]);

echo $roles;

if($roles = 1) {

    //Username

    $results3 = mysql_query($check);
    $arr2 = mysql_fetch_row($results3);
    $results4 = ($arr2[0]);

    //Password

    $results5 = mysql_query($check2);
    $arr3 = mysql_fetch_row($results5);
    $results6 = ($arr3[0]);

    //UID

    $id1 = mysql_query($check3);
    $arr4 = mysql_fetch_row($id1);
    $id = ($arr4[0]);

    echo 1;

}

else if($roles = 2) {

    //Username

    $mresults3 = mysql_query($check);
    $marr2 = mysql_fetch_row($mresults3);
    $mresults4 = ($marr2[0]);

    //Password

    $mresults5 = mysql_query($check2);
    $marr3 = mysql_fetch_row($mresults5);
    $mresults6 = ($arr3[0]);

    //UID

    $mid1 = mysql_query($check3);
    $marr4 = mysql_fetch_row($mid1);
    $mid = ($marr4[0]);

    echo 2;

};
```

However there is something wrong with my if / else if for some reason the echo shows 21 when I use a user with a userrole of 2, I want it to be either 11 or 22 :/

Comment: The `;` at the very end of your code isn't necessary.

Comment: Please fix your question title. If/else absolutely does work.

Comment: whats with all the numbered users lately? I see them more and more.

Comment: If you use a google account to sign in you end up with a randomly generated username such as this. :(

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to use `==` for comparison instead of `=`:
Change

```
if($roles = 1)
```

to

```
if($roles == 1)
```

and

```
else if($roles = 2)
```

to

```
else if($roles == 2)
```

If you use assignment (`=`) instead of comparison (`==`) it will not only evaluate to true, but it also will change the variable.

Answer (score 1):

You're setting the value of `$roles` instead of checking for equality. Try changing your code to:

```
if($roles == 1) {
  ...
}
else if ($roles == 2) {
  ...
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Typos everywhere:

```
if($roles = 1) {
```

should be

```
if($roles == 1) {
```

The first one is doing an assignment, so the if() is doing an asignment. The new version is doing a comparison instead, and can potentially evaluate to false.

Answer (score 0):

Change

```
if($roles = 1)
```

by

```
if($roles == 1)
```

same for

```
else if($roles = 2)
```

Answer (score 0):

So is there any reason you can't just do this (no `if`/`else`)?

```
$check = ("SELECT username FROM users WHERE username = '$us3r'");
$check2 = ("SELECT password FROM users WHERE username = '$us3r'");
$check3 = ("SELECT userID FROM users WHERE username = '$us3r'");
$check4 = ("SELECT userrole FROM users WHERE username = '$us3r'");

//Role

$role = mysql_query($check4);
$arr5 = mysql_fetch_row($role);
$roles = ($arr5[0]);

echo $roles;

//Username

$results3 = mysql_query($check);
$arr2 = mysql_fetch_row($results3);
$results4 = ($arr2[0]);

//Password

$results5 = mysql_query($check2);
$arr3 = mysql_fetch_row($results5);
$results6 = ($arr3[0]);

//UID

$id1 = mysql_query($check3);
$arr4 = mysql_fetch_row($id1);
$id = ($arr4[0]);

echo $roles;
```

Answer (score 0):

Hmmm...

I'm not a big PHP programmer, but the `if` statement not working caught my attention:

```
$roles = ($arr5[0]);
if ($roles = 2) {
```

is not doing what you think. That's a *set value* equals sign. What you're doing is setting the value of `$roles` to 2.

So, why would you want to set something in your `if` statement?

You can then do things like this:

```
if (($roles = $arr5[0]) == 2) {
```

Here, I'm setting the value of `$roles` and checking the value at the same time.

In most modern programming languages, you use a doubled up equals sign to test for equality:

if ($roles == 2) {

PHP also has a triple equal sign which can test not only for equality, but sameness.

if ($a === $b) {

Not only are `$a` and `$b` equal to each other, but they're also the same type.

Answer (score 0):

to let you know, your whole code makes absolutely no sense.
instead of 2 pages it have to be of just a few lines.

```
$us3r = mysql_real_escape_string($us3r);
$sql  = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE username = '$us3r'"; 
$res  = mysql_query($sql); 
$userdata = mysql_fetch_assoc($role); 
// now you have all user's data in the $userdata array.
// echo $userdata['username'];  for example will echo a username
// no need for the separate queries, no need to write the same code twice.

// and, finally
echo $userdata['userrole'];
//it seems the only thing your code does - echoing the actual userrole value:
```